# Use jQuery datatables server-side processing with mvc. Serialize criteria form and add this parameter to $ajax.post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatables

I am using mvc and jquery datatables, with serve side processing.

I have created two Class Model:
the first jQueryParamModel, to pass dataTables parameters to action controller

```
public class JQueryDataTableParamModel
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Request sequence number sent by DataTable, same value must be returned in response
    /// </summary>       
    public string sEcho{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Text used for filtering
    /// </summary>
    public string sSearch{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of records that should be shown in table
    /// </summary>
    public int iDisplayLength{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// First record that should be shown(used for paging)
    /// </summary>
    public int iDisplayStart{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of columns in table
    /// </summary>
    public int iColumns{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Number of columns that are used in sorting
    /// </summary>
    public int iSortingCols{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Comma separated list of column names
    /// </summary>
    public string sColumns{ get; set; }

}
```

the second rapresent two custom search criteria

```
 public class Home2Model
    {
        public CriteriaModel SearchCriteria1 { get; set; }
        public CriteriaModel SearchCriteria2 { get; set; }
    }
```

After i have created a strongly typed view with Home2Model, named index.cshtml

```
 @model GenericSearch.UI.Models.Home2Model

<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/dataTables/demo_table.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

  

  $(document).ready(function () {
        var oTable = $('#myDataTable').dataTable({
            "bServerSide": true,
            "sAjaxSource": "/Home2/AjaxHandler",
            "bProcessing": false,
            "sServerMethod": "POST",
            "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

                aoData.push({ "name": "hm", "value": $("myForm").serialize() });

                $.ajax({
                    "dataType": 'json',
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": sSource,
                    "data": aoData,
                    "success": fnCallback
                })
            }
        });
    });


 </script>

    <h1>Search</h1>
<br />
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home2", FormMethod.Post, new { id="myForm"}))
{
   

 <div >
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SearchCriteria1)
        @Html.EditorFor(m => m.SearchCriteria2)
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="default" value="Filter" />
        <br /><br />
        <table id="myDataTable" class="display">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>a</th>
                    <th>b</th>
                    <th>c</th>
                    <th>d</th>
                    <th>e</th>
                    <th>f</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

}
```

I have created a contoller action that recives an input in these parameters:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AjaxHandler(JQueryDataTableParamModel param,Home2Model hm)
    {
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
```

JQueryDataTableParamModel bind works properly, but hm param isn't valorized (null). the mvc binding doesn't work correctly.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$("myForm").serialize()` won't cut the mustard here. First `$("myForm")` is a selector that is looking for a tag `<myForm>` which I guess doesn't exist. You are probably looking for a `<form>` tag with id="myForm" in which case the correct selector would have been `$('#myForm')`.

This being said, the `.serialize()` method will simply turn the form input fields into `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` payload. But when you pass that to the `hm` parameter it obviously won't work. You need the entire request payload to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` if you want the model binder to be able to deserialize it properly.

So let me suggest you the [`following extension`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/29407):

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = {};
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function () {
        if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
            if (!o[this.name].push) {
                o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
            }
            o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
        } else {
            o[this.name] = this.value || '';
        }
    });
    return o;
};
```

Once you have declared it you can simply do that:

```
$('#myDataTable').dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/Home/AjaxHandler",
    "bProcessing": false,
    "sServerMethod": "POST",
    "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
        var formData = $('#myForm').serializeObject();
        for (var key in formData) {
            if (formData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                aoData.push({
                    name: key,
                    value: formData[key]
                });
            }
        }

        $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
            "type": "POST",
            "url": sSource,
            "data": aoData,
            "success": fnCallback
        })
    }
});
```

and the 2 arguments of your `AjaxHandler` action will now be correctly bound. Simply inspect the `Network` tab in your javascript debugging tool to see the difference between the 2 payloads and you will understand why your code didn't work.